# Is there a Scala.js / Relay library out there?

Tags: graphql, relayjs, scala.js, sangria

On the server side, there is Sangria, but there doesn't seem to be any GraphQL library for Scala.js, let alone a Relay binding.  Am I just not looking hard enough or is there a technical issue?

Comment: Comon, you should know questions like this are offtopic. This looks like a library request.

Comment: Yabbut I'm running out of ideas...

Comment: Have you tried Apollo? http://dev.apollodata.com/ Should be easy to integrate whatever since it has no particular build tool needs. Happy to work together to make it fit your needs!

Comment: If you haven't done so already, I'd recommend asking on the `scala-js/scala-js` Gitter channel, which is where most of the activity in the community happens...